# Should a video that is not attached to the DOM autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Here are three scenarios:

1. `document.adoptNode`,
2. `document.importNode` and
3. `document.createElement`+assign props.

In each case the video autoplays even though it's not attached to the DOM.  This is inconsistent with the behavior of a `<script>` element which wouldn't eval/download until it's attached to the DOM.

Should the video autoplay?

https://gist.run/?id=cb657718c3b6b34c043b34f3356d5a84

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GistRun</title>
</head>
<body>
  <template>
    <video src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"
           loop controls autoplay>
    </video>
  </template>
  <script>
    let template = document.querySelector('template');

    // SCENARIO 1: (causes autoplay)
    document.adoptNode(template.content);

    // SCENARIO 2: (causes autoplay)
//    document.importNode(template.content, true);

    // SCENARIO 3: (causes autoplay)
//    let video = document.createElement('video');
//    video.autoplay = 'autoplay';
//    video.controls = 'controls';
//    video.loop = 'loop';
//    video.src = 'http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: that's my question

Answer (score 0):

it's a copy vs cut difference.

In adoptNode you're cutting out something which is already interpreted, if you will, whereas in importNode you're copying a node (i.e. producing a description of that other thing), and then using that description to implement it on the dom itself.

So which is the correct behavior? Both are; one is a cut, the other is a copy. Autoplay is that which can only happen to a thing, rather than to a description of a thing. So whatever operation has furnished a description (rather than a thing), then that operation is not one for which autoplay applies.

Comment: I edited the question- apologies for the confusion.  It appears that both `importNode` and `adoptNode` autoplay.  I was missing the `deep` argument on the `importNode` call.  This: `document.importNode(template.content);` should have been this:  `document.importNode(template.content, true);`